# Google analytics reporting zero seconds sessions

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, onload

I tried to figure out why do I have so many Google analytics report of zero seconds sessions. Finally I understand that my script function below is being identified as a popup window. Can anybody help me to figure out what coud cause that? I look at a Powermapper that reported that there is a popup being blocked in my webpage. I did not inserted any intentional popup inside my webpage.

Answer (score 1):

why are you adding your google analytics code inside another function? Google provides the analytic code for you to insert as the first item on the head of the webpage like the following:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=USER_PROPERTY_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'USER_PROPERTY_ID');
</script>
```

The only thing that you need to add Google Analytics is to place those 2 script tags on the head of every web page and replace the USER_PROPERTY_ID with your own UA-XXXX-XX value.

Best Regards,
Rafael

Comment: Hello Rafael, thank you for your response. I am not adding any function inside google analytics script. This is another script outside google analytics script. I am using this another script to set different component property to the same component depending on the position of the user in my page.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing my webpage I founded that there is one script code that I placed in my webpage related to the SSL company. Seems that this script code is opening a popup on mouse scrow. I do not know why I never realize that before but seems to be fixed according to Powermapper. I will continue to monitor google analytics results.